# Schema doesn't recognise productionCompany

Tags: schema.org

I'm using [Schema](https://schema.org) to format an address like so:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/productionCompany">
    <span itemprop="name">Production Company Name</span>
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">Address goes here</span>
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">London</span>,
        <span itemprop="postalCode">N1 000</span>,
    </div>
Phone: <span itemprop="telephone">0203000000</span>
Fax: <span itemprop="faxNumber">0203000001</span>
</div>
```

Using [Google's structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/), I'm getting the following validation error:

> @type productionCompany (The type productionCompany is not a type
>   known to Google.)

This is strange, because I've found the company type [here](https://schema.org/productionCompany). Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`productionCompany`](http://schema.org/productionCompany) is a property, not a type.

In Schema.org, a property always starts with a lowercase letter, while types always start with an uppercase letter.

It seems that you want to say something about a company. In that case, you should use [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) or one of its sub-types, e.g., [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness):

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <!-- … -->
</div>
```

The `productionCompany` property takes `Organization` (or one of its sub-types) as value. So you could for example say that a certain `Movie` was produced by this company:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
  <div itemprop="productionCompany" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <!-- … -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That makes more sense, thank you. I've found a good list here with all of the different business categories: http://schema.org/docs/full.html.

Comment: @Sam: Another way to find suitable types is to start at a type you know is relevant (like `Organization`) (or `Thing` if you don’t know yet) and go down the hierarchy → [see my answer with details](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/92108/17633)