# Can I use articleBody on NewsArticle?

Tags: schema.org

Example:

```json
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "NewsArticle",
"articleBody":"The body of my article."
```

Can I do it? I saw on Schema.org that `articleBody` is property of `Article`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Schema.org type, you can use all properties that are listed in the first (not the second!) table of the type page.

As `articleBody` is specified in the first table on [the `NewsArticle` page](https://schema.org/NewsArticle), you can use it.

#### How it works

A property has a domain which says on which type(s) it can be used. For the [`articleBody`](https://schema.org/articleBody) property, it says:

> **Used on these types**
>   `Article`

A type can have parent and children types. A type always inherits all properties from all of its parent types. For the [`NewsArticle`](https://schema.org/NewsArticle) type, the parent types are:

> `Thing` > `CreativeWork` > `Article`

So a `NewsArticle` is also an `Article`, which is why `articleBody` can be used.

([more details about all this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/92108/17633))

Answer (score 0):

As you are told to ***unor*** you can use this property, however ...

Your specified markup is JSON-LD. If you install this property there, then you practically duplicate the content of your article in JSON-LD. It can be assumed that the article is the main content of the web page and occupies a large part of the web page. Thus, you double the source code of the web page, which will have a negative impact on the speed of loading the web page for mobile users. But, this is the **[search rank signal for Google](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2018/01/using-page-speed-in-mobile-search.html)**.

In addition, there is simply no place in the SERP to show the whole body of the article as an **[rich result](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2017/12/rich-results-tester.html)**. Probably for this reason, **[Google does not support this property](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article)**.

It can be assumed that the use of this property can only have an indirect negative impact on your web pages but not help with attracting organic traffic and target users.